# Blog pages/articles/url linking using neo4j

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher

I have website running with different articles and faq pages. I just want to link these pages based on topics [image] i have attached one example. please let me know if we can create relationship for different links using neo4j hence i can add the graph in to the front end for topic navigation

Comment: Are you asking (not sure) if the graph that you are showing can be stored in Neo4j ? Yes, it can.

Comment: Yes, I am looking for a solution like in the example . Could you please give me some idea how we can do it

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do experiment yourself a bit, it is a very basic graph you've got there. Here's some statements to get you started :

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (k:KnowledgeArticle) ASSERT ka.title IS UNIQUE;
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (t:Topic) ASSERT t.title IS UNIQUE;
CREATE (t1:Topic {title: "zzz"})
CREATE (k1:KnowledgeArticle {title: "xxx"})
CREATE (k2:KnowledgeArticle {title: "yyy"})
CREATE (k3:KnowledgeArticle {title: "aaa"})
MERGE (k1)-[:HAS_CHILD]->(k2)
MERGE (k1)-[:HAS_CHILD]->(k3)
MERGE (k1)-[:HAS_TOPIC]->(t1);
```

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Tom

Comment: Tom, thanks for the update and support, yes i am trying on this but i am able to create an populates code but i am looking for a way to use the url instead of  KnowledgeArticle, can we use hyper links here ?

Comment: You want the actual URL as the label of the node, not as a (String) property ? You can do that (although I do not understand why you would want to), just use backticks around the url (I notice they are not shown on Stackoverflow)  : CREATE (k1:`www.yoururl.com/1` {title : "xxx"})